# XSLT: adding text to a self-closing tag in XML

Tags: xslt

i'm trying to add text to an empty/self-closing tag.

i would like to transform something like "**<empty/>**" into "**<empty>*some text*</empty>**".

this is a shortened version of my xml i'm working on:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
<attr tag="00080090" vr="PN" pos="-1" name="Referring Physician's Name" vm="0" len="0"/>
</dataset>
```

i would like to get this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
<attr tag="00080090" vr="PN" pos="-1" name="Referring Physician's Name" vm="0" len="0">this is the inserted text</attr>
</dataset>
```

but instead i end up with an unmodified xml. it seems my match is not working if there is no text existing for this tag. it works if there already is some text, it replaces the text in this case, which is fine for me.

my XSL(T) looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="attr[@tag='00080090']/text()">
  <xsl:text>this is the inserted text</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

i did my testing with http://xslttest.appspot.com

any hints?

Comment: Whats your input xml?

Comment: see above, in the 1st code-block of my question: the XML with that one line of code, "<attr tag="00080090" ..."

Comment: You're matching on attr/text() but the attr element is empty so it does have any text nodes; just match on the attr element itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XSLT should be as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="attr[@tag='00080090']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:text>this is the inserted text</xsl:text>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: great, thank you! there's only one small side effect: it appends the text to possibly already existing text; the tag may be empty (self-closing) or already contain text, both cases should be handled, i need to set/replace the text; how can i make that sure?

Comment: You could add an empty template to ignore any pre-existing text within the `attr` element: `<xsl:template match="attr[@tag='00080090']/text()"/>`.  Or you could omit `node()` in the last `select` attribute (assuming you only want to copy the attributes of the `attr` element, not any content).

Comment: thank you Thomas W, omitting the last `node()` is doing exactly what i need.